# Filter a List from item 0 to item 314

Tags: list, listview, filtering, netlogo, items

I have a list of coordinates (xcor and ycor) of the position of citizens. To calculate this position, I associated the position of the houses with the position of the citizens. However,  I have more houses than citizens and I would like to cut the list of the location of citizens to only maintain 314 citizen's position (that it is the population of my municipality).

The code I am using is this.

show count Citizens

If count Citizens > 314

```
  [set LocationCitizens filter [item > 314 LocationCitizens] LocationCitizens]
```

I got an error in item > 314. How can I filter the LocationCitizens list to only maintain from 0 to 314 items?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNwzh.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`item`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#item) primitive allows you to extract a particular item from a list, but it won't give you back the item number and you cannot use it in a filter expression like this.

What you need instead, simply enough, is [`sublist`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#subliststring):

```
set LocationCitizens sublist LocationCitizens 0 314
```